# Free tool for manipulating XML and XSD

Tags: gratis, xml

I need a free tool (software, IDE, whatever really) that

- can generate XML files from XSD (multiple XSD’s if possible), and the opposite.
- has a graphic help.
- validates XML/XSD.

So far [XmlSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) seems to do the trick but it's not free. I’ve also tried [XmlPad](http://wmhelp-xmlpad.software.informer.com) but it doesn’t support generation of XML files from XSD.

Another thing is that I thought [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org) can do those things but alas I couldn’t do again the generation of XML files from XSD, no idea if a plugin is needed though (that would be the best approach for me since I'm already using Eclipse for development).

Answer (score 3):

I've found that there aren't a whole lot of good freebies any more, which is a shame. As a professional .Net developer I do tend to use Visual Studio and there is a free Express Edition which you could use, however there are some limitations. You cannot:

- Create an XML schema from an XML instance document.
- View XSLT output from the XML Editor.
- No smart validation while editing XSLT style sheets.
- No XML Schema Explorer.

These may be deal breakers for you, or maybe not, however good and full-featured xml editors are hard to come by gratis these days: Most of the good ones have been bought, like XMLPad (now a paid for app) and a whole host of others.

I haven't tried it yet but there is one free editor I found called [XML Copy Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xml-copy-editor/) which is free and seems to be a current project. I am about to try it myself since I'd like something more lightweight than Visual Studio.

One slightly leftfield option might be XML Notepad 2007. This is still [available](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7973) from MS and Codeplex for free but it is looking a little dated and hasn't been touched since 2007 so may have bugs or fewer/older version of features you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the python library [xmlschema](https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/) which seems to hit all of your points other than the Graphic Help. Both Python and it are free & cross platform.

- Full XSD 1.0 and XSD 1.1 support
- Building of XML schema objects from XSD files
- Validation of XML instances against XSD schemas
- Decoding of XML data into Python data and to JSON
- Encoding of Python data and JSON to XML
- Data decoding and encoding ruled by converter classes
- An XPath based API for finding schema's elements and attributes
- Support of XSD validation modes strict/lax/skip
- Remote attacks protection by default using an XMLParser that forbids entities
- XML data bindings based on DataElement class
- Static code generation with Jinja2 templates